# Does Voldemort know about the Invisibility Cloak?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, deathly-hallows, invisibility-cloak

Voldemort is keen to get his hands on the Elder Wand over the course of *HP and the Deathly Hallows*, but never seems to show any interest in either of the other Hallows.

I can't see him caring about the Resurrection Stone, since he loves nobody but himself (though the thought of him bringing his mother back to talk to her is intriguing!). But what about the Invisibility Cloak? Even if he doesn't see any value in it for himself, he'd surely recognise it as a useful thing for his enemy to possess - and yet he never shows any desire to destroy it or take it from Harry.

#### Did he ever know about the Invisibility Cloak as a Hallow, and that Harry had it?

(For that matter, did he ever know that the Elder Wand was one of the Hallows, or was his thought process more like "powerful wand? WANT!" without being aware of its symbolic significance?)

Comment: I can’t imagine he could possibly know about the Elder Wand without knowing about the cloak. I’d say that bit is a pretty sure _yes_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not necessarily. Remember Hermione knew about the Elder Wand as just a powerful wand before she believed in the Hallows.

Comment: I suppose you could say that Voldemort never knew about the Elder Wand, either—like Hermione, he just knew that there were extraordinarily powerful wands in existence, one of them being the fabled ‘death stick’. It just seems unlikely to me that he would find out about the death stick—including, importantly, the legends surrounding how it changes allegiance—without ever finding out about and linking it to the Hallows. He _was_ rather good at fishing out information, after all, and the Hallows aren’t that difficult to find (certainly not compared to the entrance to the Chamber of Secrets).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: that's easily explained.  So far as we know, he found out everything he knew about the Deathstick from Ollivander.  He had no reason to think Ollivander didn't know everything there was to know, and was in a hurry so would be unlikely to research it as thoroughly as he otherwise might.  (He didn't even bother to question Grindelwald, if you remember.)

Comment: You meant "powerful wand? POWERFUL WANT!", right?

Comment: I always kind of took Voldemort's pursuit of the Elder Wand and dismissal of the Resurrection Stone and Cloak of Invisibility as a literary device to double down on the notion that Voldemort's hubris was part of his downfall. I personally thought that JKR could have improved the greater narrative by having Voldemort come into possession of all three Hallows at points throughout the story and foolishly discard both the Resurrection Stone as well as the Cloak of Invisibility since they were not the Elder Wand, thereby discarding the things that would all but guarantee his victory.

Comment: I'd like to point out that Voldy didn't discount the resurrection stone.  Or did people forget about Book 1 in its entirety?

Comment: @Draco18s resurrection stone has nothing to do with book one. That's the philosophers stone.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack Are you sure they aren't the same?  Given that the resurrection stone never otherwise appears in the books I find it suspicious that it was left out but the other two were major players.  Also remember that the wand went by many names, why not also the stone?  Also remember why Voldemort wanted the philosopher's stone: to *resurrect himself.*  Then there's Rowling's penchants for hidden details.  The stone in the first book being the third deathly hallow fits right in with her style.

Comment: @Draco18s 100000000% sure. The philosophers stone produces gold and the elixir of life, the resurrection stone brings back the already dead.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack Pretty sure he's an incorporeal entity and his body died.  So yes, I'd qualify him as in the state of being dead.  Feel free to locate a canonical reference or Word of God that says they are in fact two distinct items.  I postulated that they could be the same item, provided a couple of supporting arguments, and you've fixated on one, highly questionable, detail.

Comment: @Draco18s no. You've misread the book and made a spurious claim. It's for you to offer support for your argument. He's not dead. If you want it going further ask a question. This isn't the place for it.

Comment: While it would be fun to equate the Philosopher's Stone to the Resurrection Stone, the PS is categorically described as being created by Nicolas Flamel, who is not one of the three brothers.

Comment: @NKCampbell it's also in use at the same time that the resurrection stone is in Gaunts ring.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack Well, Gaunt's ring then.  Voldy made it a horcrux, but didn't know it existed?  That seems...odd.

Comment: @Draco18s its discussed in the books. If you'd read them, you'd understand.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack I read them.  Like 10+ years ago back when they came out.  I don't have a photographic memory, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @Draco18s its discussed two inches further down the page we're on now.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack Ah, forgot about that remark (both from the book and prior reading of this page (or possibly missed reading it in that answer entirely)), thank you. :)

Comment: @Draco18s don't forget Gaunts ring was very old, it came from the Peverall brothers (who lived in the 11th century) and there's no indication any of its owners knew it was a hallow.

Comment: Voldemort would **never** want to hide behind an invisibility cloak.

Comment: @Krumia he would never want to hide *himself* behind an invisibility cloak... but what about *a part of his soul*? I suspect (but have no canon support, unfortunately) that he wanted to turn the Cloak into a horcrux, and that he also knew that James Potter possessed it. That would explain why Voldemort was short of one horcrux the night he killed Harry's parents, and also why he never tried to steal it or destroy it after killing them (because he couldn't produce other horcruxes).

Comment: @A.Darwin: Voldemort wanted significant items for his Horcruxes.  Granted that the cloak *was* significant, all the evidence indicates that Voldemort never knew it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I' m not saying that he knew it was a Hallow. I think that he didn't know or perhaps even care about the three Hallows and the idea of being Master of Death, especially given his disregard for the Resurrection Stone. However, I do think that he knew that Harry's cloak was a significant magical object, and was no ordinary cloak. Since I cannot find evidences in the canon, I don't want to write this as an answer, but I thought I could reply to those saying that an invisibility cloak would have been completely useless to Voldemort.Just my $0,02.

Comment: @A.Darwin: it is my belief that, if Voldemort knew about James' cloak at all, he thought it a bog-standard one, inferior to his own magic.  But I can't think of any explicit evidence for that offhand either.  Perhaps this should be a separate question?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> “And Voldemort never knew about the Hallows?”
>
> “I do not think so, because he did not recognize the Resurrection Stone he turned into a Horcrux. But even if he had known about them, Harry, I doubt that he would have been interested in any except the first. He would not think that he needed the Cloak, and as for the stone, whom would he want to bring back from the dead? He fears the dead. He does not love.”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35: King's Cross*

Dumbledore suspects that Voldemort did not know of the Hallows (especially since he was raised by muggles and wouldn't have heard the children story) and that even if he did, he obviously did not care about them, since he had in his possession the Resurrection Stone, and didn't appear to know.

The Elder Wand, on the other hand, was not known exclusively for being a Hallow, as Hermione knew the existence of powerful wands, but not of the Hallows.

> “The Deathstick, the Wand of Destiny, they crop up under different names through the centuries, usually in the possession of some Dark wizard who’s boasting about them. Professor Binns mentioned some of them, but oh, it’s all nonsense. Wands are only as powerful as the wizards who use them. Some wizards just like to boast that theirs are bigger and better than other people’s.”
>
> “But how do you know,” said Harry, “that those wands — the Deathstick and the Wand of Destiny — aren’t the same wand, surfacing over the centuries under different names?”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 21: The Tale of the Three Brothers*

It's key to note that, while the above established that Voldemort most likely did not know that the cloak was a Hallow as Nkrisc's quote shows, he definitely **KNEW** Harry **HAD** a cloak.

Comment: Dumbledore says *the benefit* of the invisibility cloak hallow is its ability to protect others, something Voldemort is not interested

Answer (score 39):

There's a moment in *The Deathly Hallows* where Harry, Ron, and Hermione apparate into Hogsmeade while it is under control of the Death Eaters. They trip the Caterwauling Charm and are hiding under the cloak. The Death Eaters come out looking for them, but can't see them. One of them tries the summoning charm on the cloak:

> *“Accio Cloak!”* roared one of the Death Eaters.
>
> Harry seized its folds,
>   but it made no attempt to escape: The Summoning Charm had not worked on it.
>
> “Not under your wrapper, then, Potter?” yelled the Death Eater
>   who had tried the charm, ….
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*,
>   Chapter 28: The Missing Mirror</sup>

indicating they know it's likely the trio hiding under an invisibility cloak. If rank and file Death Eaters knew that Harry Potter used an invisibility cloak, it's extremely likely that Voldemort knew.

EDIT:
While I think it extremely likely that Voldemort knew Harry Potter possessed an invisibility cloak (the second part of the question) I don't think it's quite as clear as whether he knew it was a Hallow (the first part of the question), but other answers do a good job speculating on that.

Comment: Harry had 3 trademarks, using Expeliarmus in combat, the scar, and using AN invisibility cloak. Several others knew about the cloak, but, there wasn't a single cloak (except Harry's) that would function permanently, without wearing off. Harry's cloak was always useable.

Comment: Maybe this is for a question itself, but why didn't "Accio Cloak" work?

Comment: @Philbo, the charm didn't work because the cloak is a hallow

Answer (score 20):

There is no doubt that Voldemort is one of the most powerful wizards of his time. Likewise, Dumbldeore is most likely the most, however, one quote intrigues me.

> "I don't need a cloak to become invisible' said Dumbledore gently.

If Voldemort is on par with Dumbledore, he most likely does not need a cloak to make him invisible either. Due to this, **I believe he would have no use (to use) for the cloak.**

In Deathly Hallows, (part two of film), the trio interview Ollivander, and an essential piece of information is revealed.

> "It is rumored there are three. The Elder Wand. The cloak of invisibility to hide you from your enemies. And the Resurrection Stone, to bring back loved ones from the dead. Together, they make one the master of Death. **But few truly believe that such objects exist**".

Despite this, Voldemort was very sneaky, and appeared very innocent - like the time he said he was merely researching Horcruxes. **With this nature, it seems he would be interested in this** - what many would think - fairy tale, but **with his urge for power and greed, he may have overlooked it**. He has indeed overlooked extremely important things such as ancient magic in the past.

Comment: I'm not convinced that Voldermort's power is the cause of him not having a use for the cloak.  I think his arrogance and desire for respect because of his power would mean he wouldn't want to be invisible.  He would want to be seen when he is moving around.  Sure he avoids being seen when he is raising his army and building his power, but generally speaking, he wants to be seen

Comment: The Cloak really is kind of the lamest of the Hallows.  Sure it sounds handy, but if any sufficiently skilled wizard can do the same thing on their own, it's not all that impressive unless you collect the whole set.  And now you're using up three whole item slots for - oh wait, gamer-brain just took over there for a second...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I thought the implication was that the cloak actually did do more than just keeping you invisible, keeping you _hidden_ i.e. prevent such things as people running into you while you're invisible. I don't think this is elaborated upon anywhere, but it'd be hard to believe the cloak is just a perma charmed invisibility cloak.

Comment: This is implied, but it doesn't feel entirely consistent with the descriptions in the books of sneaking around (avoiding bumping/being bumped/being heard). Note that the wearer also appears on the Marauders map.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have the text handy for a direct quote, but I recall that place where Harry, Ron, and Hermione each choose a different Hallow as the *obvious* best of the three. I think this is an important part of the story. The Hallows represent kinds of temptation, and different people are more or less susceptible to different temptation.

Voldemort's temptation was the wand, and would always be the wand, whether or not he knew of the others.

That said, Voldemort's ultimate goal was to beat death, something explicitly promised by the Legend of the Deathly Hallows. I think that, if he knew of the legend, he would have relentlessly pursued all three artifacts. Voldemort may not have desired the individual powers provided by either the cloak or the stone, but I believe he would have strongly considered the idea that uniting the three could provide the owner with the power of immortality, creating a new power that none of hallows possessed individually. That would be too good a chance for him to pass by.

For this reason,  I believe Voldemort had not heard the full legend. The passage from chapter 35 of DH quoted in another answer lends credence to this view, though I disagree with that character's view of what Voldemort would have done had he known.

Of course, you could also argue that Voldemort was aware of all the Hallows, and merely chose to focus on the wand *first*. Once acquiring the wand, he may have then moved on to the cloak or the stone. Even raised by Muggles, one would think that one of the Death Eaters, knowing his goal, would have brought this story to his attention at some point. But I find the idea that he had not heard the legend somehow more compelling, especially given he turned the Stone into a horcrux.

Comment: Considering how many people saw the Hallows story as a mere children's tale, it also wouldn't be too surprising if Voldemort or his followers didn't take the story seriously, and discovered the Elder Wand as an unrelated (but obviously very potent) instrument of magical power.

Comment: Just a children's tale, yes... but one that explicitly promised Voldemort's greatest desire. It would have been just too good to pass up. We have plenty of evidence of other adults following the legend... Xenophilius Lovegood, Grindelwald, Dumbledore. I believe Voldemort still would have investigated, had he known, which would have led to a much earlier and more complete encounter with Grindelwald.

Answer (score 3):

The quote that [Himarm found](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116166/30482) contains the key:

> “The Deathstick, the Wand of Destiny,
>   they crop up under different names through the centuries,
>   usually in the possession of some Dark wizard who’s boasting about them. 
>   Professor Binns mentioned some of them, but — oh, it’s all nonsense. 
>   Wands are only as powerful as the wizards who use them. 
>   Some wizards just like to boast
>   that theirs are bigger and better than other people’s.”
>
> ︙
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*,
>   Chapter 21: The Tale of the Three Brothers</sup>

The owners of the Elder Wand *boasted* about it, and used it
(presumably in quite visible fashion) to defeat other wizards —
and were, subsequently, killed *because* they possessed the wand. 
Thus, its existence was widely known. 
The Invisibility Cloak, on the other hand,
is a defensive weapon that works on the principle of stealth. 
Its value and power are diminished when your adversary knows that you have it
(note that Draco was able to petrify Harry on the Hogwarts Express
while Harry was cloaked), so its owners kept it a secret.

**TL;DR**: I find it perfectly plausible that Voldemort did not know
that the Invisibility Cloak existed.

Answer (score -2):

### Yes. According to newly released canon, Voldemort was searching for the Hallows, and thus knew about the cloak.

From the Timeline in the updated edition of Cursed Child:

> "Voldemort murders Snape to obtain the Elder Wand **in his quest to unite the Deathly Hallows.**"

[image: timiline]
.

Comment: ughh...another reason to thoroughly dismiss TCC. There's never any indication given in the books that Voldemort wants the wand for anything other than finally having the ultimate weapon with which to defeat Potter. Dumbledore even *says* Voldemort didn't know about them

Comment: @NKCampbell I agree. Not liking CC though, is not a reason do downvote my answer (something that others seemed to do.)